# Error while loading dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I am trying to load a dataset that I downloaded from this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkY2lFgS9uiDdDdxazdLMnUwalpyMjc0UlY1U2p4cnc#gid=0

I downloaded it into my C drive in this location C:/CDA drive as popular.tsv

I am trying to read it into a dataframe.  I use both source and load and I get an error in both of them.

```
>present=source("C://CDA//popular.tsv")
Error in source("C://CDA//popular.tsv") : 
  C://CDA//popular.tsv:1:9: unexpected symbol
1: gender  grade
       ^
> present=load("C://CDA//popular.tsv")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘popular.tsv’ has magic number 'gende'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 

>present=read.table("C://CDA//popular.tsv")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 23 did not have 11 elements
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `source` and `load` and not `read.table` and family?

Comment: present=read.table("C://CDA//popular.tsv")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 23 did not have 11 elements

Comment: try `read.table("C://CDA//popular.tsv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong functions to read the data in.

`load` is for data files which have been saved using R's saved objects (usually files ending with ".Rdata" or ".rda"). `source` is generally used to read files or connections containing R scripts.

You should try `read.table` and family. Since this is a tab separated file, you can use:

```
read.delim("C://CDA//popular.tsv") 
## ^^ is the same as `read.table(..., header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
## see ?read.table for more details
```